# factorial negative

Tags: factorial

I do not understand how the following simplification has been performed:
$$\sum_{n=4}^7 \frac{n!}{(n-2)! (n-(n-2))!} = \sum_{n=4}^7 \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}$$

The problem I have is the "n-" in (n-(n-2))!

Could you please explain it to me stepwise ? Thanks

Comment: $(n-(n-2))=(n-n+2)=2$ so $(n-(n-2))!=2!$... note in general that $a-(b-c) = a-b+c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have,

$(n-(n-2))!$

$=(n-n+2)!$

$=2!$

Comment: Thank you, absolutely simple..

Comment: Mine pleasure..